# How to install libxml2 for C in OS X?

Tags: c, macos, libxml2

how to install libxml2 in OS X?

EDITED:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml2>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

> error: 'libxml2' file not found

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  Libxml2 is just built into Mac and the headers ship with XCode.  Type `man libxml` at the command prompt.  libxml2.dylib is in my Mac's /usr/lib folder.

Comment: @selbie Thank you, you are right, but, I get an error in my code. I edited my question.

Comment: None of the code you included references any libxml functions. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @duskwuff yes, but I'm trying(as test) include the library.

Comment: Then why did you include the rest of your example code? Please reduce questions to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, you can install libxml2 using:

`brew install libxml2`

Comment: libxml2 comes with OS X. This won't fix their other problems.

Answer (score 2):

To use libxml2, or any shared library, you need to...

- Include the right header files in your code.
- Add the path to the header files.
- Add the path to the shared libraries.
- Add the shared library.

The [libxml2 docs](http://www.xmlsoft.org/docs.html) aren't the best, but there are some [code examples](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html) to draw from. And from that we see we need to `#include <libxml/component.h>` where `component` is whatever piece of the library you're including. For example, if you want to write XML documents, it's `#include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>

int main() {
    // Just something to demonstrate we can call functions and the linking worked
    xmlTextWriterPtr writer = xmlNewTextWriterFilename("example.com", 0);
    // Just something to do with the variable.
    printf("%p\n", writer);
}
```

Then you need to find the header files. OS X comes with libxml2 installed, but it's in `/usr/include/libxml2`. So that needs to be added to the include path with a `-I/usr/include/libxml2`.

The headers contain the definitions of the various functions, but the real code lies in shared libraries. Those are in the normal location, but you have to tell the compiler it to use it with `-lxml2`. Fortunately they're in the default location, so we don't have to add to the normal search path for shared libraries (that would be `-L/some/path/`).

Put it all together...

```
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -Wall test.c
```